# A "direct" proof that hyperbolic groups are not amenable

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

I am looking for a proof that a finitely generated hyperbolic groups is non-amenable [unless it is virtually cyclic] which is as "metric/combinatoric" as possible.

Here are the two proofs I am aware of: 1) use the arguments similar to "the centraliser of an element of infinite order is virtually cyclic" to show there is actually a free group [unless the group is virtually cyclic], 2) construct a Floyd boundary (or other ideal boundary) and ping-pong a free group out of the action on the boundary.

To make things slightly more precise, for a [finite] generating set $S$ and for a finite set $F$, define $\partial_S F$ to be the set of edges between $F$ and its complement in the Cayley graph with respect to $S$.

$\mathbf{Question:~}$ What is a reference for a "as direct as possible" proof that a finitely generated hyperbolic groups satisfy: given $S$ as above, there is a $K>0$ such that for all $F$ finite, $|\partial_S F| \geq K |F|$?

Both proofs above use quite heavily the algebraic side of the problem. And there is a minimal algebraic content to any proof of the above implication: it is easy to construct a non-Cayley graph counter-example to the above question (take any hyperbolic Cayley graph and add a half-line to it).

[Edit: just ignore this PS]
PS: If it helps, one could assume that the group is finitely presented (i.e. it is the $\pi_1$ of some compact manifold). In fact, I would be delighted to see that this extra assumption can really be put to use.

[Edit: as suggested by Yves in the comments...]

$\mathbf{Possible~motivation~and~alternate~question:~}$ Given a quasi-transitive hyperbolic graph $\Gamma$, does it satisfy a "strong" isoperimetry, i.e. $|\partial F| \geq K |F|$ for some $K>0$?

Definition of quasi-transitive: there are constants $C$ and $L$ so that the set $SQI_{C,L}$ of all $(C,L)$-quasi-isometries from $\Gamma$ to itself is transitive, i.e. for any vertices $x$ and $y$ there is a $\phi \in SQI_{C,L}$ so that $\phi(x) =y$.

Comment: I am slightly puzzled, because if you are talking about Gromov/word hyperbolic groups, then they are all finitely presented, so why are you writing "finitely generated hyperbolic group" and why might one not assume that they are finitely presented?

Comment: oh yeah, my bad! I got confused while writing this down. I think I meant that one could take this for granted (even if the proof of this fact might feel algebraic and not combinatoric to some). As for the "finitely generated", there are some people looking at hyperbolic groups which are not finitely generated, see "Amenable hyperbolic groups" by Caprace, Cornulier, Monod & Tessera. But yes, I was pedantic in writing this.

Comment: The classical books about word hyperbolic groups are written for finitely generated groups, and finite presentability is one of the first theorems proved about them. So writing "finitely generated hyperbolic groups" is perfectly natural, and writing "finitely presented hyperbolic group" would either sound as an unnecessary restriction, or as redundant. (By the way, Gromov used **hyperbolic groups** to mean a group endowed with a left-invariant distance that is a hyperbolic metric space, and specified to finitely generated groups with word metric as **word hyperbolic groups**).

Comment: Antoine, you could ask about a quasi-transitive, finite valency graph (in the sense that there exist $C,C'$ such that $(C,C')$-self-quasi-isometries are transitive on the graph. I'm not sure it's know that under these conditions, (hyperbolic with at least 3 boundary points) implies non-amenable. It's true for transitive graphs.

Comment: @Yves, oh, yes that would make a much more interesting question! I'll edit it into the post.

Comment: @Yves: what are examples of quasi-transitive finite valency graphs which are not quasi-isometric to transitive graphs?

Comment: @Mikael See Elek & Tardos "On roughly transitive amenable graphs and harmonic dirichlet functions" section 3. But this particular example is "amenable".

Comment: @Mikael: take a generic enough connected Lie group and consider a metric lattice (=Delone subset) inside. By generic enough, I mean: not quasi-isometric to any finitely generated group (this holds for semidirect products $\mathbf{R}\ltimes_{(e^t,e^{bt})}\mathbf{R}^2$ for $b\notin\{1,0,-1\}$, which are hyperbolic for $b>0$ and not (metrically) amenable, or for some one-parameter family $(G_t)$ 7-dimensional 3-step-nilpotent simply connected *nilpotent* Lie groups when $t$ is transcendent, using Pansu's theorem).

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle PS: in my previous comment I mean "not QI to any transitive graph". This is stronger than "not QI to any f.g. group", but for hyperbolic Lie groups and groups with polynomial growth it's the same, so in particular the examples I gave are fine (at least for $b>0, b\neq 1$ in the first one).

Comment: Thanks Yves. What is a reference why it is the same?

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle First, "QI to a transitive (finite valency) graph" is the same as "QI to a CGTDLC group" (Compactly Generated Totally Disconnected Locally Compact). Second, Trofimov proved that any transitive graph of polynomial growth fibers with finite fibers to a graph with discrete automorphism group (that is, a f.g. group modulo a finite subgroup) and the LC counterpart (Lozert) is that any CGTDLC group of polynomial growth is compact-by-discrete. (...)

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle (...) In the hyperbolic case, the arguments are in 6C of my survey http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.2229v2. In short: for $b>0$, $b\neq 1$, Pansu's results imply that any CGLC group QI to the 3-dimensional Lie group I mentioned, say $H_b$ is also focal; but a totally disconnected focal group has a totally disconnected boundary while the boundary of $H_b$ is a 2-sphere. So $H_b$ is not QI to any CGTDLC group.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle: btw, for an arbitrary hyperbolic connected Lie group I'm not sure that my claim that "QI to any transitive graph" and "QI to any f.g. group" are indeed equivalent. This would follow from the Hilbert-Smith conjecture (using the action on the boundary). But actually this is also conjecturally equivalent to the very restrictive "acts geometrically on some rank 1 symmetric space of noncompact type".

Comment: Don't know direct or not but one can construct nontrivial quasimorphisms explicitly on hyperbolic groups (see the work of Hamenstatd or Calegari and Fujiwara). This means that the second bounded cohomology is nontrivial. Hence the group is not amenable.