# Presentation of hyperbolic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Is it true that all hyperbolic groups are finitely presented? If yes, what is the right reference for that?

Comment: Any book covering hyperbolic groups will have this result. If you prefer, you can refer to Gromov's "Hyperbolic Groups" essay.

Comment: I believe that Gromov's original definition included groups that are not finitely generated, and he called them *word hyperbolic* if they are. (See discussion here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/233957/) It is true and easy to prove that finitely generated hyperbolic groups are finitely presented.